# Opening bootstrap modal with double click

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm trying to open a modal double clicking. I'm using this piece of code but it's not working:

```
$('#link').dblclick(function () {
  $('#myModal').modal('toggle');
});
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/labanino/JKEj3/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove `data-toggle="modal"` from the link..

```
<a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" id="link">Launch modal</a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JKEj3/3/

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove `data-toggle="modal"` from button definition.

http://jsfiddle.net/JKEj3/5/

Answer (score 0):

```
     this._ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
        $(document).on('click', "#moD1", () => {
            this.closePopovers();
            this._ngZone.run(() => {
                this.openPopUp();
            });
        });
        $(document).on('click', "#moD2", () => {
            this.closePopovers();
            this.openPopUp();
        });
        $(document).on('click', "#moD3", () => {
            this.closePopovers();
            this.openPopUp();
        });
 });
 //popover close
closePopovers() {
    $(".popover").fadeToggle(150);
    $('.popover').not(this).popover('hide');
    $("div[id^='popover']").popover('destroy');
}

openPopUp(){
    const dialogRef = this._matDialog.open(YourComponent, {
                width: '900px',
                data: {
                    taskId: task._id,
                    tabIndex: 1
                },
                panelClass: 'full-width-modal'
    });
}
```