# Open modal on double click using data-toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using data-toggle to display a modal when a text area is clicked.
It is working well but I want to display the modal on double click (ondbclick)as apposed to on single click(onclick).
Below is my textarea.

```
<textarea rows="2" cols="70" class="col-lg-10 col-md-9 form-control input-long" data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" name="textArea" id="text_area"></textarea>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap for this?

Comment: You should do it it without using data-toggle. have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16726303/opening-bootstrap-modal-with-double-click) question where they dont have `data-toggle=modal` but still use it on a double click. keeping it there ensures that it happens per click (thats what data-toggle does)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using Bootstrap for this, which seems to be the case given the `data` attributes in use, then you will need to trigger the modal manually through code as the inline `data` attributes are designed to work with `click` events only. Try this:

```js
$('#modal').modal({
  show: false
});

$('textarea').on('dblclick', function() {
  $('#modal').modal('show');
});
```

```css
#modal {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #FFF; 
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<textarea rows="2" cols="70" class="col-lg-10 col-md-9 form-control input-long" name="textArea" id="text_area"></textarea>
<div id="modal" class="modal">
  Hello World
</div>
```